# Как пробросить файл на сторонний сервер

Tags: node.js, express

Добрый день!

У меня есть API-сервер на express.js, который служет прослойкой между моим FrontEnd и удаленным сервером. Возникла задача сохранения/получения файлов на/с удаленный сервер. Сейчас я получаю FormData, сохраняю временный файл у себя на сервере и, затем, отправляю его на удаленный сервер.

Вопрос в следующем: Я могу как-то пробросить поток файла сразу на удаленный сервер (или, обратно, поток получаемого с удаленного сервера файла), минуя сохранение на диск на своем локальном API-сервере?

Answer (score 1):

Да, например используя [request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(request.put('http://mysite.com/img.png'))
```

или

```
fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.put('http://mysite.com/obj.json'))
```